# Multiple Azure Antivirus installed VMs needs to be subscribed to Azure message queue using Peeklock model

Tags: azure, publish-subscribe, azureservicebus, azure-sdk

We have installed sophos in multiple Azure Linux VMs. Installed pip , azure service bus sdk and using the below code we are able to consume message when it arrives in queue.

```
from azure.servicebus import QueueClient, Message # Create the QueueClient
queue_client = QueueClient.from_connection_string("<connectionstring>", "taskqueue") # Receive the message from the queue with queue_client.get_receiver() as queue_receiver: 
messages = queue_receiver.fetch_next(timeout=3)
for message in messages:
    print(message)
    message.complete()
```

How do we exactly subscribe multiple AV servers to the message queue using peek lock model. Peek lock ensures if first AV Linux VM picks up the message and initiates the scan, the message should stay locked with that particular VM only, no other VM should pick this up.

1. Can we do event based polling using SDK. Is it advisable to do continuous polling.
2. How do we set up the peek lock model- When a message arrives , any one AV scan VM should consume the message and lock it so that any other VM does not pick up.
3. Although there are multiple AV scan VMs , only one should pick up the message. Should we use Service bus queue/topic. 
   End goal is: AV VMs should be subscribed to the Service bus

Answer (score 0):

**1 -** While Storage Queues don't yet support events, [Service Bus supports Event Grid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-to-event-grid-integration-concept) but currently just in the Premium Tier.

Also, in the case of Service Bus, the SDK uses AMQP by default which uses an full-duplex open connection.

**2&3 -**  For queue storage, when one receiver fetches a message, that message becomes invisible to other receivers until a specific timeout. Read more about [concurrency in the queue service in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-concurrency#managing-concurrency-in-the-queue-service).

For service bus, you can use the [peek-lock mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-transfers-locks-settlement#peeklock) to achieve the same. In this case, you can also renew the lock for delayed processes.

Answer (score 0):

Its working now:
How do we exactly subscribe multiple AV servers to the message queue using peek lock model. Peek lock ensures if first AV Linux VM picks up the message and initiates the scan, the message should stay locked with that particular VM only, no other VM should pick this up.

1.Can we do event based polling using SDK. Is it advisable to do continuous polling.-***Yes we can do event based polling. We configured long polling.***
2.How do we set up the peek lock model- When a message arrives , any one AV scan VM should consume the message and lock it so that any other VM does not pick up.-***Its done using Azure service bus sdk. python code attached below.***
Although there are multiple AV scan VMs , only one should pick up the message. Should we use Service bus queue/topic. End goal is: AV VMs should be subscribed to the Service bus- ***While multiple call to the services are made, the scripts in multiple VMs continues polling. Available VM takes up and completes the scanning.***